# 3D parametric graph in Gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot, parametric-equations

Currently, I'm trying to create a 3d parametric graph similar to this: 
[image]

which can be found here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/surface1.html.

With script here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/surface1.17.gnu

My graph looks like this:

[image]

and I'm using this:

```
set datafile separator ","
set parametric
x0 = 0 
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
splot 'January5.csv' u x0:1:3 with lines, 'test.csv' u x1:1:2 with lines
```

Obviously my graph is lacking in comparison. I really like the ability of the first graph in plotting along the x-axis. I've been trying to replicate this, but have been failing so far.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of your data, just to know what the three dimensions really are and how z varies as a function of x and y?

Comment: Sure: 
             Z          Y
    0.158999994 83906.71679
    0.160000011 84700.96927
    0.174999982 84700.96928
(The first is the Z, the second is the Y, and for the X I want to use an arbitrary number to organize the graphs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to rely on `parametric` if you just want to plot raw data from a file.

With sample data `xyz.txt` that looks like noisy sinusoidal time-series:

```
1 0 9.43483356296457
1 0.0204081632653061 10.2281885806631
1 0.0408163265306122 10.9377108185805
...
3 0.959183673469388 10.2733398482972
3 0.979591836734694 10.1662011241681
3 1 10.4628112585751
```

(First column is an integer values coding x locations, 2nd and 3rd columns are for y and z. I appended the R script I used to generate those data at the end.)

I would simply use

```
splot 'xyz.txt' using 1:2:3 with impulses
```

where `impulses` draws vertical lines from the minimum of z. You can change this bevahior; for example, if you want to start at z=0, you could use

```
set zrange [-1:12]
set ticslevel 0
zmin = 0
zr(x) = (x==0 ? zmin : x)
splot 'xyz.txt' using 1:2:(zr($3)) with impulses
```

Note that I used regularly spaced values for y, but that doesn't really matter.

[image]

Other variations are possible, of course. Maybe [Fence plots with a some-liner](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/07/fence-plots-with-some-liner.html) or [Wall charts](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/wall.html) might be of further assistance.

---

**[R](http://cran.r-project.org/) script used to generate `xyz.dat`:**

```
n <- 50  # number of observation per sequence
k <- 3   # number of sequences
t <- seq(0, 1, length=n)  # sampling rate
xyz <- data.frame(x=rep(1:k, each=n), y=t, z=sin(2*pi*t*2.1)+.25*rnorm(n*k)+10)
write.table(xyz, file="xyz.txt", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: I have one problem with my current graph. I need the Y axis to be time formatted (so there aren't breaks from times that don't exist: 9:60-9:99), but Gnuplot isn't recognizing timefmt for more than just seconds.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but with data (min:sec) like this `2:30 3.1 \ 2:35 4.7 \ 6:48 9.4 \ ...`, a command like `set xdata time \ set timefmt "%m:%s"` would work. (But see also http://1.usa.gov/xJP8Zu.) Could you perhaps be more precise?