# Fence plot (or Wall plot?) density plots in R or GNUPLOT

Tags: r, gnuplot, histogram, density-plot, fence-plots

Hi I have some ensembles for stochastic simulations of a system. I would like to represent these data as histograms in a fence plot in a similar way to what is shown here:

[3D parametric graph in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009154/3d-parametric-graph-in-gnuplot)

http://lee-phillips.org/qdf/

http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.mx/2009/08/return-of-wall-chart-entirely-in.html

However, I am not sure about how to do it with histograms (in principle, it is quite confusing for me to make histograms in GNUPLOT, I've already checked [Histogram using gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot) and some other posts). I know how to make histograms in R and I've successfully tried things like this:http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.mx/2013/04/rg10-plotting-multiple-suprimposed.html
http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/06/28/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-1/

My data looks like this:

```
 #              time                  Aa                  As
 0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 5.000000000000e-01  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 1.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 1.500000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 2.000000000000e+00  2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 2.500000000000e+00  2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 3.000000000000e+00  2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 3.500000000000e+00  2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 4.000000000000e+00  2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 4.500000000000e+00  3.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 .
 .
 0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 5.000000000000e-01  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 1.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 1.500000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 2.500000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 3.000000000000e+00  2.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 3.500000000000e+00  3.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 4.000000000000e+00  3.000000000000e+00  0.000000000000e+00
 .
 .
 .
```

I have around 1000 different stochastic simulations and I want to plot together density plots for the Aa column in different times, for example time zero, 100 and 1000. And make it look like the firsts posts I included here. I hope this post is enoughly clear. Please let me know I you need any further information.